# Angular Controller not instantiating

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I'm working on a small project using AngularJS. Sometimes, when I load the page, AngularJS doesn't instantiate.

I call ng-app in the html tag, link to angular using the CDN in the head, and then call ng-controller in the body tag.  Any idea what's going on?

Also - I changed the start/end symbols to {[{ and }]} due to conflicts with Flask.

MCVE example:
This project requires python and flask.
**app.py**

```
from flask import *
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/getReducedMatrix/", methods = ["POST"])
def getMatrix():
    entries = request.get_json()
    dict = {"original": entries}
    return json.dumps(dict, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5001)))
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="LinAlgToolkit" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js" type = "text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="/static/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <button ng-click = "displayMatrix()" type = "button">RREF it!</button>
  <table ng-if = "response != null">
    <tr>
      <th>Original Matrix</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id = "matrixMath">{[{response.original}]}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**static/script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('LinAlgToolkit', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.inputMatrix = [[2,2],[4,5]];
  $scope.error = null;
  $scope.response = null;

  $scope.displayMatrix = function(){
    console.log($scope.inputMatrix);
    $scope.response = null;

    $http.post('/getReducedMatrix/', $scope.inputMatrix)
    .then(function (matrix) {
      console.log(matrix);
      $scope.response = matrix.data;
      console.log($scope.response.original);
    });
  }
});
```

Run app.py and type 127.0.0.1:5001 into your browser. 
You should see a button with "RREF it!" - click this and an array should display with "Original Matrix" above it. This is expected behaviour.

Sometimes you'll see the button, with "Original Matrix" and "{[{response.original}]}" right below it. This can be reproduced by holding down F5 and letting go (for half a second or so).

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question so that people will be able to reproduce this problem. 
I strongly recommend to create a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You likely have an exception. Open the console and check.

Comment: @NewDev - there weren't any exceptions in the console (it's in the screenshot).

Comment: @Spike, actually there is a little red "x" on the right side. At any rate, I agree with the first comment - the question has to be self-containing without relying on links. Links are auxiliary data, including linked-to images, or links to code elsewhere

Comment: @NewDev didn't catch that - thanks! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Fedor added a MCVE!

Comment: @Spike very good, now I hope your question will receive more attention. I'll try to play with it soon